# xpath count with condition

Tags: xml, xpath, count, conditional-statements

I need to find the count of tags based on a condition.

```
<A>
  <B><C>99</C></B>
  <B><C>96</C></B>
  <B><C>98</C></B>
  <B><C>95</C></B>
  <B><C>99</C></B>
</A>
```

I have come up this far

```
count(//*A/B/C/[text() = '99' | text() = '98'])
```

The expected output will be 3

I am not an expert in xpath, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
count(/A/B/C[text() = '99' or text() = '98'])
```

`*` means any element. It would work with `/*/B` because `A` is an element. `[]` means a predicate which restricts the node it's applied to. Since it applies to `C` you don't use any path separator between `C` and the predicate. `//` means descendant or self. Since your root is `A` it makes no difference if you use `//` or `/`. If you didn't care about context and just wanted to count all `C`s in your document, independent on where they are located in the tree you could also use:

```
count(//C[text() = '99' or text() = '98'])
```

If there were any `C`s in other parts of the document they would also be counted. When it makes no difference, like in your case, it's more efficient to write the full path.

Comment: You can simplify this further, to `count(//C[text() = ('99','98')])`